# How to make a HTTPS request using HttpClient in Java with no certificate authentication or hostname verification?

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpclient

Can someone tell me how to issue a HTTPS request using HttpClient v4.1 without **any** verification regarding the hostname and certificate. I've read a lot of questions and forums and tried a lot of different things, eventually ending up with this:

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
context.init(new KeyManager[] {}, new TrustManager[] {}, new SecureRandom());
SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(context, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme("https", 443, sf));
```

...then when I go to make the request, I get:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

**I am aware that what I am trying to do is not secure.**

Comment: So if you don't want it secure why use HTTPS at all?

Answer (score 0):

the trick is part - "**.loadTrustMaterial(null, (chain, authType) -> true)**", pass in trustStrategy that alwasy return true, then you can skip the local certificate host name verification, and it will also work when you modify your host file to apply a domain - IP mapping.

```
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        FileInputStream keyStoreFile = new FileInputStream(CERT_PATH);
        ks.load(keyStoreFile, CERT_PASSWORD.toCharArray());

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts
                .custom()
                .loadKeyMaterial(ks, CERT_PASSWORD.toCharArray())
                .loadTrustMaterial(null, (chain, authType) -> true)
                .build();

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

        Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder
                .<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                .register(REST.HTTPS.LABEL, sslConnectionFactory)
                .register(REST.HTTP.LABEL, new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
                .build();

        BasicHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);

        httpClient = HttpClients
                .custom()
                .setConnectionManager(connManager)
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionFactory)
                .build();
```

Answer (score -1):

This did the trick, in addition to the other lines above. There's just so many variations and versions that I got lost in them all:

```
    context.init(new KeyManager[] {}, new TrustManager[] {new X509TrustManager() {
        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {return null; }

        @Override    
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)throws CertificateException {}

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)throws CertificateException {}

    }}, new SecureRandom());
```

I'll mention it again, **this is not secure, don't do it unless you know what you're doing.**

Comment: It isn't valid for `getAcceptedIssuers()` to return null.